# gitlab helm chart shibboleth configuration

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, single-sign-on, saml, shibboleth

i am self hosting a gitlab instance in a kubernetes cluster. My configuration is done via helm chart. Now, I want to use shibboleth as a sso provider.
The documentation is a little bit lacking on the shibboleth site.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/shibboleth.html

To my progress so far, via git.example.com/Shibboleth.sso/Session i already get Attributes, Logging in and Out is already working but via https://git.example.com/users/auth/shibboleth/callback, like it should be according to the documentation, i simply get a
"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."

Alternately to this, the saml approach according to
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/saml.html?tab=Helm+chart+%28Kubernetes%29

Via the url: https://git.example.com/users/auth/shibboleth/callback

I get the following error:

"Could not authenticate you from SAML because "Saml response missing".

Does anyone has a clue, at least how to start troubleshooting?
Does anyone have experience in using shibboleth and kubernetes gitlab via helm chart?

Cheers